# Boost Serialization: pointer conainer to <BASE> contains various of DERIVED objects

Tags: c++, pointers, serialization, boost, polymorphism

I have a type class Node with serialize method.
There are derived classes of Node: BigNide, SmallNode.. (and more). and derived classes of them- VitalBigNode.
Every one of them also has serialize method which calls the serialize method of the base of him. (via the serialization::base_object).
Until now, serialize works perfect for every kind of node.

Here is the tricky part:
There is a list container of (Node*)s (pointers to Node), which contains objects from various kinds of Nodes (the derived classes).
I want to serialize this container. I've tried desperately many combinations of uses of unique_ptr, shared_ptr, polymorphic, BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT etc for vain.

The list 'serializer' relates every object in the list as a pure Node object. It calls the serialize method of Node class. Of course, It throws an error - an ugly one.

Still trying to solve the problem, in the serialize method in Node class, I've tried to write a code to identify the derived class and dynamically cast the object to the derived cast before serialize. It is very problematic due to the fact that Node must be declared before its derived classes. Also, the DEFINITION of the serialize method must set in the Node declaration header. So I CAN'T just declare Node::serialize in Node declaration, then include derived classes and then define Node::serialize method.

There must be an adequate and known solution I've missed!

Thanks very much for helping!
Elad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a classic (and solvable) issue with Boost.Serialization. I bet you can find it answered many times on SO. Here is the summary:

A. One way: After creating but before deserializing the archive, teach archive about which derived classes to expect:

```
 ar.template register_type<BigNode>();
 ar.template register_type<Node>();
```

etc. (For saving these calls are done automatically). Usually I put these calls into some function and put it into some separate file.

B. Alternative way: Create a separate cpp file and put there the macros

```
 BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(BigNode);
 BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Node);
```

It is quite important to keep them together because each macro evals to some static object and it is important that the order of initialization of these objects is robust; such robustness is only guaranteed when all macros are in the same compilation unit.

And of course, always use serialization code like "ar & p" and not "ar << *p" where p is a pointer of Base type referring to an object of derived type.

Comment: Works! Thank you very much for the fast answer!!

Comment: I'm writing a CGI library. If one wants to use the library and make his own 'Node' class, can he write "BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(MyNewNode);" in his project?

Comment: It should work fine with archives created after adding MyNewNode class. From my experience it might not work with older archives -- unless you use one of the methods above (and even there, it is safer to add BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(MyNewNode) after older macros). The reason is as follows: the macro BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT inits a local static variable to generate some class ID by putting class info into some container. If you want these IDs to be backward compatible you prefer to avoid uncertainties of "static object order of initialization".